# The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process solve

Tags: c#, jquery, c#-4.0

The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process

```cs
[WebMethod(Description = "Work Order Proposal Print", EnableSession = true)]
public string FnConsolidateApprovePrint(int PRID, int ComId)
{
    string BFtType, fileName;
    string RtnStr = "";
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    string UserFn;
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BB_PHARM_CONSTR"]);

    BFtType = "";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        SqlCon.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "workorder_proposal_report";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PRID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ComId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ComId;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "DataTable1");
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        UserFn = "WorkOrderProposal" + Convert.ToString(PRID);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (BFtType.Length > 0)
            {
                if (BFtType == "PharGen")
                    rptDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("crWOPropose.rpt"));
                else
                {
                    fileName = "Formats/" + BFtType + "crWOPropose.rpt";
                    //modified to check below line 
                    //File.Delete(fileName);
                    if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName)))
                        rptDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName));

                    else
                        rptDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("crWOPropose.rpt"));
                }
            }
            else
                rptDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("crWOPropose.rpt"));

            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);

            // Remove PrnType-related code
            rptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Print/" + Convert.ToString(UserFn) + ".pdf"));
            RtnStr = @"\\Print\" + UserFn + ".pdf";

            ClearApplicationCache();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
   
        ClearApplicationCache();
   
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        ClearApplicationCache();
        cmd.Dispose();
        if (SqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            SqlCon.Close();
    }
    return RtnStr;
}
```

Comment: Please don't submit your question if the preview shows that the formatting is a mess. If you don't know how to format code or other elements properly, consult the Help Center to learn.

Comment: Code and an error message are not sufficient. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That would include, but not be limited to, an indication of where the exception is thrown in the code. Also, what file are you trying to access? Where is it located? Are you accessing the same file anywhere lese in this application or elsewhere?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.